# Refactor javascript to create modal shell and inject values rather than create new elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have some javascript that works to create modals, but that I know I need to refactor, because it is creating the modal(s) directly in the DOM, rather than having one modal 'shell' and injecting the values into it.

I'm not sure of the best way to do this without breaking my code. I have created [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rnorris984/bcw74n0y/9/) of how my code is working now, for each individual db record I need to create an element and add some attributes to it, clicking on the element opens a modal where the data is editable, and can be submitted with the form.

My bad js in pseudo-code......

```
dbRecord.forEach(el => {
const button = document.createElement('button')
button.innerHTML = <populate some html with db info>

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    modal.style.display = 'block'
    modal.innerHTML = <set attributes from parent element>

    document.querySelector('.modalCloseButton').addEventListener('click') => {
           modal.style.display = 'none'
    }
    ...
 }
}
```

At the moment when the button is clicked it creates a new DOM element in my js, and I'm sure that most of it is not good practice, but I'm not sure of the best way to do this - should I create the element in the html and try and inject the values? Should I create a modal shell as a variable in js and re-use it somehow? I'm just very wary of 'experimenting' with this and breaking it.

Comment: I get what you're doing but not really what your actual question is? Your fiddle seems to already do what you're asking about here? Are you merely trying to improve your code? Anyway, just have a <div> somewhere set to `display: none`, and have a showModal function with a bunch of parameters that fills and displays it. You seem to be already doing this, however. And replacing a single element's `.innerHTML` over and over again is fine, in case you're wondering. It won't stack up or anything.

Comment: PS: `button.innerHTML = <populate some html with db info>` seems weird; shouldn't this just be button text? And where exactly is the listener function "creating a new DOM element"? It does overwrite the modal's innerHTML, but that's fine. PPS: re-reading your question title, if all your modals are going to have the exact same structure, you can grab child elements and fill them directly, instead of assigning a massive string to innerHTML

Comment: @Chris G Yes, that's right - the code works fine, I just really don't like it, it seems very 'unclean'. I'm just not sure how to improve it without breaking it. Thanks for the 'innerHTML' tip as well, I didn't know that.

Comment: Setting `innerHTML` of an element which has events attached (in the element itself or some inner elements) will remove the events, though.